# Alamofire.request().responseObject doesn't return response

Tags: swift, request, response, alamofire, objectmapper

I use AlamofireObjectMapper extension. I want to get response, but it's failed. My tableLeague object is always nil because code with response closure doesn't call ({ (response: DataResponse) in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            tableLeague = response.result.value
        } doesn't call). I use next methods:

```
let header = ["X-Auth-Token":"1231231"]

static let sharedInstance = ServerAPI()
private func getRequest(uri: String) -> DataRequest {
    return Alamofire.request(uri, method: .get, headers: header)
}

public func getTableLeague() -> TableLeague {
    var tableLeague: TableLeague?
    getRequest(uri: URL).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<TableLeague>) in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            tableLeague = response.result.value
        }
    }
    return tableLeague!
}
```

And use in business class:

```
public func readTableLeague() -> TableLeague {
    let tableLeague = ServerAPI.sharedInstance.getTableLeague()
    return tableLeague
}
```

I think it can be because response haven't yet but i try to set object that i haven't yet

Whats a problem? Completion handlers i need to use else?

Comment: Please add some more description about your problem.

Comment: I add more description.

Comment: Its means your Mapper class does not map the response into your TableLeague class. Please check response object contains the JSON object or not.

Comment: it is json object

Comment: {  
   "_links":{  
      "self":{  
         "href":"http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/426/leagueTable/?matchday=18"
      },
      "competition":{  
         "href":"http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/426"
      }
   },
   "leagueCaption":"Premier League 2016/17",
   "matchday":18,
   "standing":[  
      {...}
}

Comment: maybe i need to map all fields from json?

Comment: Ofcourse you have to completely map you JSON object.

Comment: But why i need to do this, if i don't need all of fields?

Comment: If you JSON object contain an array of object then you have to completely parse your object but you can skip some keys from JSON object.

Comment: After your answer(if i can skip some fields) i don't know where my map error
http://paste.ofcode.org/ptqYm4BvnqEpEzHhmu25ZR

Comment: I think you don't need to create properties. Further please read AlamofireObjectMapper guideline carefully by this https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper

Comment: Your result is nil because the network part is *asynchronous* and the nil value is returned before the network task is done. You cannot return from an asynchronous task, you have to use a callback.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to map by following structure

```
class Response: Mappable {
    var success: Bool?
    var data: [Data]?

    required init?(_ map: Map) {
        mapping(map)
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        success <- map["success"]
        data <- map["data"]
    }
}

class Data: Mappable {
    var uid: Int?
    var name: String?
    // add other field which you want to map        

    required init?(_ map: Map) {
        mapping(map)
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        uid <- map["uid"]
        name <- map["name"]
    }
}
```

When you get JSON response simple map by this syntax

```
let response = Mapper<Response>().map(responseObject)
if let id = response?.data?[0].uid {
    println(id)
}
```